# android ble connectGatt timeout

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

To save embedded device battery power, the advertising period is 10sec.
With a Samsung tablet, I succeed to scan the device with a scan period timeout of 30sec.

When I try to connect to it, nearly every time the connection is fail (error 133). Sometime it is OK. I already looked for some posts so I try to connect with the TRANSPORT_LE option.
I suspect a timeout during the connection procedure because it stops after 2 or 3 second only.

How can I specify a longer timeout for the connectGatt() procedure?

Comment: after verification the advertising period is 1.5sec ... but the issue is still here

Comment: If you are working with BLE I can suggest you to try Polidea library https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle in order to get rid of all those 133 errors

Answer (score 1):

Here is some method I address with status 133.

I add this code in callback

```
onConnectionStateChange
```

```
else if ((status == 8 && newState == 0) || (status == 133 && newState == 0)) { 
                gatt.disconnect();
                gatt.close();
                gatt.getDevice().connectGatt(getApplicationContext(), false, mGattCallback);
            }
```

I just disconnect and release all bluetooth resource with gatt.close().
Then reconnect with it again.